# How to get drive root from share path?

Tags: c#

I have a folder with some path, for example `C:\repository\data`.

I shared this folder, so it has some hostname, for example `\\10.10.10.254\repository\data`

I have a method

```
string GetDriveRootPathFromPath(IEnumerable<string> lokalPathCollection, string sharePath)
{
      var rootPath = _win32.GetVolumePathName(sharePath);
      return lokalPathCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(rootPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

they didn't work, because they cannot find disk with that name `\\10.10.10.254\`.

How can I modify this method to find disk `C:\`, in my example, because `repository\data` are located on this disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: You can't. Because a windows share doesn't contain information about the local path.

Long answer:

Since you know the IP address or hostname of the server and given that you have the permission to execute wmi queries, you could use wmi to get the information.

```
pulic string GetLocalPath(string computerName, string shareName)
{
    var scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", computerName));      
    scope.Connect();
    var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM win32_share WHERE name = '" + shareName + "'");
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope,query);
    var queryCollection = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        return m["Path"];
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
    var path = @"\\10.10.10.254\repository\data";
    var segments = path.Split('\\');

    var computerName = segments[2];
    var shareName = segments[3];
    var localPath = GetLocalPath(computerName, shareName);
    var result = Path.Combine(localPath, String.Join("\\", segments.Skip(4)));
```

Comment: I think we must set `segments[2]` and `segments[3]`, rather then `segments[1]` and `segments[2]`. And why we need last line?

Comment: @Anatoly Oh yes, I didn't comile or debug the code.
The last line was just a demo how to resolve a full path into the local path. This code would translate `\\10.10.10.254\repository\data\files\file1.txt` into `c:\shares\repository\data\files\file1.txt`
Feel free to midify the code to your needs.

Comment: I have `System.UnauthorizedAccessException was unhandled by user code Message=Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))` because I connected to my virtual machine, not to my local computer. How to resolve this situation?

Comment: @Anatoly - WMI security would be a better question for server fault. Since you are already authenticated to the servers share I suppose it is a missing permission. This should be a good starting point http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enablewmi.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may share subfolder like:

```
c:\path1\path2\myshare
```

and it will look like

```
\\127.0.0.1\mysahre
```

so your example to work all shared folders should be in the root of the drive

then you can strip the leading drive from the paths in your lokalPathCollection.
What I mean is instead of storing `C:\repository\data` , you will need to store   `repository\data`.
In such case change your line to:

```
return "c:\\" + lokalPathCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndWith(rootPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: `lokalPathCollection` contains just a drive letters, like `C:\\, D:\\, E:\\` etc